# Ionic Angularjs - Change ion-icon on Tab button (with ng-class)

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm trying to change the icon on **Tab** from *"ion-social-google-outline"* to *"ion-social-google"* when clicked, but cant figure out how to do it...

I can't use ***ion-tabs*** with ***icon-on***, ***icon-off*** because I want to navigate within a ***ion-slide-box*** and therefor I have to use ***div class="tabs"***

Here is my HTML code:

```
    <div class="tabs tabs-icon-top" ng-controller="NavigateController">
          <a class="tab-item" ng-click="navSlide(0)" >
            <i class="'icon ion-social-google-outline'"></i>
            Google
          </a>
          <a class="tab-item" ng-click="navSlide(1)">
            <i class="icon ion-ios-bolt-outline"></i>
            Electro
          </a>
     </div>
```

and this is my Controller for navigating between pages in ***Slide-Box***:

```
angular.module('app.controllers', [])

.controller("NavigateController", function($scope, $ionicSlideBoxDelegate) {
    $scope.navSlide = function(index) {
        $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.slide(index, 500);
    }
});
```

How do I change the tab icon ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do it would by using the `icon-on` and `icon-off` attributes inside `<ion-tabs>` tag. Much like this:

```
<ion-tabs>
    <ion-tab title="" href="#" icon-on="ion-gear" icon-off="ion-gear-outline">
        Tab Name
    </ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

**EDIT:**

I don't see why not, but I guess if you can't at all, then do something like this:

In your controller:

```
$scope.$state = $state;
```

HTML:

```
<i ng-class="{$state.current.name == 'tab 0': 'ion-ios-gear-outline', $state.current.name !== 'tab 0': 'ion-ios-gear'}"
```

Comment: I said that I can't use <ion-tabs>

Comment: And why can't you use it inside of ion-slide-box?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know why I couldn't use <ion-tabs> yesterday together with the Slide-Box, however you were right, I got it to work with <ion-tabs> :) thx for the help guys!

Comment: Glad it worked. Must have been a weird thing to not let it work yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a example from a app I wrote:

```
 <i style="vertical-align: middle !important; float: left; padding-right: 10px; padding-top: 0px, padding-bottom: 0px;" ng-class="{'ion-qr-scanner': item.Status == 'OPEN', 'stopiconopen': item.Status == 'OPEN', 'ion-checkmark-circled': item.Status == 'ARRIVED', 'stopiconarrived': item.Status == 'ARRIVED'}"></i>
```

if you look at `ng-class` it works like this `{'the name of the class you want to apply', : the epxression to be evaluated}`

so in your case if icon-on is being toggles true and false you could say

```
ng-class="{'icon-on-icon': icon-on, 'icon-off-icon': !icon-on}"
```